# Playhouse's (peewee extenstion) signals does not work correctly

Tags: python, peewee

I have two models: `User` and `UserSettings` because I decided to divide user related properties and privacy settings.

I am using `PeeweeORM` for building models and creating tables. Here is a short part of my code:

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    tg_id = BigIntegerField(unique=True, null=True)


class UserSettings(BaseModel):
    user: User = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='settings', unique=True)

    show_location: bool = BooleanField(default=True)
```

As far as I know `peewee` itself has no built-in `OneToOne` relation support and I have decided to use playhouse's django-like signals described in peewee docs so that there is one record in UserSettings table for each one User. As it was defined in docs, I have inherited my BaseModel class from `playhouse.signal` Model class to make signals working. Here is a signal itself:

```py
@post_save(sender=User)
def on_user_created(model_class: User, instance: User, created: bool):
    print("works1")  # Signal is working correctly. I see this output in console 
    if created:  # DOES NOT WORK HERE! I AM GETTING False value on created
        print('works2')
        us = UserSettings()
        us.user = instance
        us.save(force_insert=True)
```

So this is the way I am creating new users:

```py
def create_or_update_user_tg(tg_id: int, name: str, age: int, city: str,
                             gender: Gender, search_gender: SearchGender,
                             profile_description: str = None, location: Location = None,
                             medias: typing.List[tuple[str]] = None) -> \
        typing.Union[User, None]:

    u, is_creating = User.get_or_none(tg_id=tg_id), False

    if not u:
        u, is_creating = User(), True

    u.tg_id = tg_id
    u.name = name
    u.age = age
    u.city = city
    u.gender = gender.value
    u.search_gender = search_gender.value
    u.profile_description = profile_description

    if location:
        u.longitude = location.longitude
        u.latitude = location.latitude

    u.save(force_insert=is_creating)

    upload_user_medias(u.tg_id, medias, delete_existing=True)
    return u
```

Thanks for responses guys! Waiting for your advices.

Comment: Here is official docs on signals: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#signal-support

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine for me. Here's a stripped-down, simplified example:

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse.signals import Model, post_save
from uuid import uuid4


db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class User(Model):
    id = UUIDField(default=uuid4)
    username = TextField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

db.create_tables([User])

@post_save(sender=User)
def on_save(model_class, instance, created=None):
    print(instance.username, created)

u = User()
u.username='foo'
u.save(force_insert=True)
u.save()
```

The output, as expected:

```
foo True
foo False
```